# ordering a list through a function

Tags: python, list

Could you help see what's wrong with my code? In an exercise, I want to order a list.

```py
def order_num(a_list):

    list = []
    for i, j in a_list:
        if i > J:
            list.append(i)
            a_list.remove(i)
        elif i == j:
            list.append(i)
            a_list.remove(i)
        else:
            list.append(j)
            a_list.remove(j)
    print(a_list)


the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
order_num(the_list)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/a1c53481210f2aad/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    order_num(the_list)
  File "/tmp/sessions/a1c53481210f2aad/main.py", line 4, in order_num
    for i, j in a_list:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Comment: What do you mean by ordering a list ?

Comment: Did you mean `for i, j in enumerate(a_list):`? That code will only work if the list being iterated is a 2 element iterable (e.g. tuple, list). Usually a cleaner approach is to build a new list, instead of trying to manipulate the existing one.

Comment: It looks like you want to compare two continuous values of the list. `i` refers to the previous element and `j` as the current element?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you show in your question isn't runnable. Please show the code you actually tried.

Comment: I am trying (while exercising functions in python) to write a function that sorts a list of integers. I know of the built inf function sort() and sorted() but the idea here is to think of the best function implementation to solve this. so through i and j I was trying to compare the elements of the list and add the bigger number to a new list. By the way thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to take two elements of a_list when iterating over it. It does not work this way.
When looping over your list, your code should look like this:

```
for val in a_list:
```

You can keep the item from the previous iteration in a variable that you can declare before the loop and initialize it to 0 (assuming this is an integer list that you are sorting in ascending order). Your code would look something like this:

```
previous_val = 0
for val in a_list:
   if previous_val > val:
...
   previous_val = val
```

I'll let you figure out the rest of your assignment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess this solves it. I was trying to iterate over the list of integers ans have the function compare the elements of the list and to add the bigger int to a new list and then print it out, hence having an ordered list.

Comment: Hello gchapuis. I have tried your solution but it gave me an unexpected result:

Comment: @Ben, what unexpected result did you get?

Comment: @gchpuis it gives me a truncated list instead of the original list. for instance I give it a list of 10 int, it gives me back a list of two int.

Comment: You're gonna have to post your code so we can understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

First two issues:

- Your code sample has a variable `J` which I presume is `j`
- Your code sample has a variable `a_liste` which I presume is `a_list`

The reason your code isn't working is because you are trying to "unpack" a list. You can unpack a tuple, but to iterate through a list, you only call one variable at a time, like:

```
for i in a_list:
    #  do something with i
```

If you want to compare two items within your list, one option is to iterate a second time.

```
for i in a_list:
    for j in a_list:
```

Or you might want to think about iterating through the indices of the list using `for i in range(len(a_list)):` instead.

Comment: I am trying (while exercising functions in python) to write a function that sorts a list of integers. I know of the built inf functuon sort() and sorted() but the idea here is to think of the best function implementation to solve this. so through i and j I was trying to compare the elements of the list and add the bigger number to a new list. By the way thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Better to ask this comprehensively as an edit in your main post, or a new post, rather than a comment.